# Typescript generics take an object of type and return type method return type

Tags: typescript

Take two base classes

```
interface Entity {}
interface Model {
  toEntity(): Entity;
}
```

I need to make a method that takes a derivied class of Model and converts it to entity preserving the generic class

```
function convert<T extends Model, J extends T['toEntity']>(model: T) { 
  return model.toEntity();
}
```

However this yields

```
Type Entity is not assignable to type J. J could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to Entity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want the Model parameterized by Entity? [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2AeAUXGDAE8A%20ZAbwChl7kx0iwTSAKASgC5kW2A3DQC%20NGjACuIBK3QhkCOQDdoYQsTLl2AWyy5eGbPn6aefDaWp0GUCGAlR5uowDomJjpyGia2BDjhbBTkAZzBkZ300PXwwqFAAc3IhRRAw5AgLZABeYJAVKDAdGK8gA)

```
interface Model<Entity> {
  toEntity(): Entity;
}

function convert<Entity>(model: Model<Entity>): Entity {
    return model.toEntity();
}
```